# Error while reinstalling MikTeX

Tags: installing, miktex2.9

I had installed MikTeX with "only for me" option and it was running fine. However I needed a "for all user" for it to work with some other app. Therefore I attemeted to uninstall MiKTex and reinstall it with "for all users" option.

However, everytime after the basic MiKTeX installer has completed copying files it shows the following error.

[image: Setup Error]

The log report after extraction is as follows:

> updating package manifests ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/config\package-manifests.ini")...
>   installed 3558 package manifests
>   visiting repository C:\Users\bidit\AppData\Local\Temp\mik11850...
>   repository type: local package repository
>   loading package repository manifest...
>   initexmf "--common-install=C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9" --set-config-value=[Core]SharedSetup=1 --admin "--log-file=C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/config\uninst.log" --disable-installer --verbose:
>   Option --admin only makes sense for a shared MiKTeX setup.
>
> Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed for the following reason:
>
> Option --admin only makes sense for a shared MiKTeX setup.
>
> An error occurred:
>    source file: 
>    source line: 0
>    message: The executed process did not succeed.
>    info: fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\initexmf.exe", exitCode="1"

I also tried by deleting all the files in Program Files and AppData folder, cleared the registry (using CCleaner). From the error I think the local installation is not completely removed.

Can someone suggest me if there are some other residual files that need to be deleted or any other way to install?

Comment: Did you uninstall the old installation as user and changed then the user to administrator for the admin installation (better install then complete MikTeX) ...

Comment: Many users prefer to use portable MiKTeX. Assuming portable MiKTeX is unpacked/installed in `D:\PortableApps\MiKTeX\texmfs\install\miktex\bin\`, one simply has to add this location to PATH either under *user variables* (alternative to "only for me"), or under *system variables* (e.g. "for everybody").

Comment: @Mensch I am not sure I understood your question. I have only one account in my computer (which is an administrator accont). I installed, then uninstalled using the standard Windows 10 apps and feature setting and then tried to reinstall using the same account but last time for all users.

Comment: @BiditLamsal For security reasons you should not work with an admin acoount. If you catch an virus, it has admin rights too -- that is very bad and very dangerous! Usual working is to have two account on an computer, one user account for doing TeX, email etc. and an admin account for administration reasons only ...

Comment: @Mensch Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @andselisk I will try that and check if the program I am trying to work with will recognize it.

Comment: @BiditLamsal If you are using `Windows OS`, then please install in `Admin` rights..